# How can I cut the face flange (no nail fin) off my replacement window to make it a box window for my masonry install?

Tags: windows

I purchased AWP vinyl replacement windows with the face flange but they are too large.  If I cut the face flange off they will be perfect.  What do I use to cut the 5/8" flange off each side?

Answer (score 2):

Vinyl windows for "new construction" can usually have the nail fin cut off with a knife or saw. Then you install the window using the replacement or upgrade instructions. Usually consisting of screws in the sides, insulation and shims.

Comment: Be careful in how you fasten the insert window into the wall frame. Ideally, you would screw into the window frames along the glazing seat (glass removed from the window) and into the wall frame (Min. 1" of the screw inside the wall framing). Apply a bead of sealant on top of the fastener head and replace the glass (and glazing stops) back into the window.

I would recommend asking the window supplier/manufacturer for install steps or methods for installing your window through the frame (nailing flanges removed).