# Fastening modified, vinyl, new construction window into a wooden jamb

Tags: windows, replacement, window-frame, jamb

I am trying to see if I can salvage a **vinyl** new construction window that has a nail fin/flange (for nailing the window directly to the house framing) for use as a replacement window by cutting the nail fin/flange off.

I found [this answer on DIY.SE](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/138306/87068) that seems to indicate this is possible to do, my only concern is how to nail the vinyl window into a wooden jamb (left behind from the previous/existing window being replaced). Is there a trick here, or am I attempting the impossible/impractical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can fasten the window without using the nail flanges. Windows without flanges are typically called "block frame" windows in my area.

Fastening the windows into the wall opening requires shimming and screws driven through the window frame into the jamb of the framing.

Without more details as to what type of window and jamb that is as much instruction as can be given. Obviously the screws need to be placed so that they do not interfere with the window operation. Also, special consideration needs to be given to the waterproofing between the window and the opening. Nailing flanges really help with the waterproofing.

Comment: I think the key here is _SCREW_ the window into place through the frame, not _nail_. Using screws allows one to back them out a bit if you've over tightened and bowed the frame so the windows don't operate properly. Much more difficult to do that with nails.

Comment: I'm leaning towards the [Pella 150 series](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Pella-Vinyl-Replacement-White-Double-Hung-Window-Rough-Opening-24-in-x-36-in-Actual-23-5-in-x-35-5-in/1002641642) @Kyle (thanks and +1). My concern would be how to drive a nail/screw through the inside of the "channel" (the part where the sashes slide up/down) into the jamb. If they are metal or made from some material that would crack or shatter then it's either a non-starter or is made much more complex. Thanks for any and all help here, both of you!

Comment: I agree, though this likely voids manufacturer warranties if not done according to the literature. Some windows will have holes punched in the sash channels as position indicators.